# i am facing issue while building my projects which were created o previous version and now in 2.8.0 these are not working

Tags: flutter, gradle, build

[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1**strong text**

Comment: Are you able to create and run new test project successfully with latest version?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have replace my android folder with the other project and it works for me